# Difficultty in understanding Dependency Injection in Spring MVC project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have just started learning SPRING and during reading I found one of the important feature of Spring is Dependency Injection.

Then I came across the following demo of Spring project http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/ . I understand What is Dependency Injection and all that stuff.

But, I am having problem in understanding that this project (link I have given above) has dependency injection injected in  it or not ? If it is can explain how  ?and if not then how can I inject in this project ?

Thanks

Comment: Each time you see `@Autowired`, a dependency is injected in an object. So yes, the tutorial uses dependency injection.

Comment: ok. But I have read that (DI increases the possibility to reuse classes and to test them independently of other classes(Unit Testing)). Is the Unit testing pass through here ? or this is good enough to test the class independently ?

Comment: That's indeed one of the main advantages of dependency injection. Unfortunately, the author of the tutorial neglected to implement unit tests for its code. That doesn't mean it's impossible. And that doesn't mean he's not using dependency injection. Using a car allow going very far in a short time. That doesn't mean that if you take your car to go a few miles away, you're not using a car. EDIT: I just read the two questions at the end of your previous comment, and I don't understand them. Please clarify.

Comment: then can you give me a hint how to implement Unit testing in this demo?

Comment: An answer would be several pages long. So here's a hint: you unit-test a service depending on a DAO by creating an instance of the service class, and injecting a mock DAO inside. The DAO does what you tell it to do, which allows testing the service without a database. Same for the controller, that you can test by injecting a mock service.